# PLSQL - Cursor cannot be used in dynamic sql

Tags: plsql, dynamic-sql

I have a dynamic SQL query which is constructed in a string.
The procedure should return a 'REF CURSOR'.

I get the error **PLS-00455** when I try to open the cursor for the query.

**Cursor definition**

```
  CURSOR cu_SiteList IS
  SELECT SEC_NN.SRV_ID
        ,SEC_NN.SRV_NAME
        ,SEC_NN.SRV_COMTYP_CODE
    FROM SEC_NN
        ,COM_SITE_STATE_T
   WHERE SEC_NN.SRV_COMTYP_CODE <> 1
     AND SEC_NN.SRV_ID = 2;

  TYPE SITE_LIST_TYP IS REF CURSOR RETURN cu_SiteList%ROWTYPE;
```

Here is the query:

```
p_SiteList  SITE_LIST_TYP;
        lv_QueryStr := ' SELECT SEC_NN.SRV_ID ' ||
                       ' ,SEC_NN.SRV_NAME ' ||
                       ' ,SEC_NN.SRV_COMTYP_CODE ' ||
                  ' FROM SEC_NN_, ' ||
                               ' COM_SITE_STATE_T ' ||
                             ' WHERE SEC_NN.SRV_COMTYP_CODE <> 1 ' || 
                               '  AND SEC_NN.SRV_MODE_CODE = 2' ||
                               '  AND SEC_NN.SRV_ID = COM_SITE_STATE_T.SRV_ID';

OPEN p_SiteList FOR lv_QueryStr;
```

As you can see I only use 3 columns from SEC_NN table, so creating a cursor that is a ROWTYPE of the entire table will not work for me.
How can overcome this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'I get the error when I try to open the cursor'. **What error?**  Please edit your code to include the code that is opening the cursor and also the error message you receive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't we use strong ref cursor with dynamic SQL Statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783461/why-cant-we-use-strong-ref-cursor-with-dynamic-sql-statement)

Comment: @LukeWoodward, I don't think so, I saw that post earlier, that is the way my cursor is configured. Updated original post.

Comment: Can whatever is using the ref cursor use a 'weak' ref cursor instead?  (Try declaring `p_SiteList` of type `SYS_REFCURSOR` instead of `SITE_LIST_TYP`.)  If yes, then that's your solution.  If not, then you may be stuck.

Comment: I think I can do that.

Comment: @LukeWoodward, Tried the weak cursor and it works fine. Now I've added RANKs (rownum) and I get Oracle ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel. Any idea why?

Comment: ORA-03113 is caused by a server process crashing, basically it's an Oracle bug.  To keep this question focused please ask a separate question with the SQL query that reproduces the ORA-03113 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, the fix is to declare the cursor as a 'weak' ref cursor, by replacing the line

```
    p_SiteList  SITE_LIST_TYP;
```

with

```
    p_SiteList  SYS_REFCURSOR;
```