# Error opening cursor from dynamic SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I am working with Oracle PL/SQL cursors. I have created a cursor but I am unable to open it. I am getting errors like:

> Error(51,13): PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed

I get error for opening cursor statement as well.

This is my code :

```
DECLARE

   uldid uldlog.uldid%type;
   flightlegid uldlog.flightlegid%type;  
   TYPE rec IS RECORD (uldid number, uldlog number);
   --CURSOR some_cursor RETURN rec;
   CURSOR distUld return rec;  
   ress rec;


BEGIN

      MainQuery1 :='select uldlog.uldid, uldlog.flightlegid 
      from uldlog
      INTO distUld
      INNER JOIN flightulds ON uldlog.uldid = flightulds.flightuldsid 
      INNER JOIN M_ULDTYP ON FLIGHTULDS.ULDTYPEID = M_ULDTYP.ULDTYPID 
      INNER JOIN FLIGHTLEG ON FLIGHTLEG.FLIGHTLEGID = FLIGHTULDS.INFLIGHTLEGID
      INNER JOIN FLIGHTS ON FLIGHTLEG.FLIGHTID = FLIGHTS.FLIGHTID
      INNER JOIN M_AIRLINE A on A.AIRLINEID = FLIGHTS.AIRLINEID
      INNER JOIN m_flighttyp on m_flighttyp.Id=FLIGHTLEG.SERVICETYPEID  
      INNER JOIN m_pax_fr on m_pax_fr.id=m_flighttyp.pax_fr_id
      where flightulds.uldtypeid IN (3,4,5,8,9)';          

      FinalQuery1 := MainQuery1 || CommonFilterCluase || ' GROUP BY uldlog.uldid, uldlog.flightlegid';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FinalQuery1;          

   OPEN distUld;
   LOOP 
      FETCH distUld into ress;
      EXIT WHEN distUld%notfound;
      NumberOfUldsDistinctEntires := NumberOfUldsDistinctEntires +1;   
      IF fn_bdtimedifference(uldid,flightlegid,FlightTypeIds,CargoType,CargoPriority,UldTypes,SlaStatusCommaSeparatedNumbers) is null then
      Bd_Avg_Time := Bd_Avg_Time + 0;
      Else 
      Bd_Avg_Time := Bd_Avg_Time + fn_bdtimedifference(uldid,flightlegid,FlightTypeIds,CargoType,CargoPriority,UldTypes,SlaStatusCommaSeparatedNumbers);
    END IF;
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE distUld; 
END;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your cursor declaration `CURSOR distUld return rec` is wrong. It looks like you're trying to do:

```
TYPE distUld IS REF CURSOR return rec
```

but [you can't use a strongly-typed ref cursor with dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2783461/266304). So you can't have the return. You also need an instance of that type, and instead of the `execute immediate` - which should not have the `into` clause - you open the ref cursor  dynamically:

```
DECLARE
  ...
  TYPE distUldType IS REF CURSOR;
  distUld distUldType;
BEGIN
   MainQuery1 :='select uldlog.uldid, uldlog.flightlegid 
      from uldlog
      INNER JOIN flightulds ON uldlog.uldid = flightulds.flightuldsid 
      ...';
   FinalQuery1 := ...;

   OPEN distUld FOR FinalQuery1;
   LOOP 
      FETCH distUld into ress;
      EXIT WHEN distUld%notfound;
      NumberOfUldsDistinctEntires := NumberOfUldsDistinctEntires +1;   
      IF fn_bdtimedifference(ress.uldid, ress.flightlegid,
         ress.FlightTypeIds, ...) is null then
      ...
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE distUld;
END;
```

There are other problems that are outside the scope of the original error, but essentially `rec` has to have fields for every column you select in the cursor query, and the cursor query has to select every column you want to pass as an argument to your functions, and those calls have to qualify the field names with the `ress` record variable. So your query has to get `FlightTypeIds` etc. from the appropriate tables; and `rec` needs fields to hold those columns.

You're also missing declarations for `MainQuery1`, `FinalQuery1`, `CommonFilterCluase`, `NumberOfUldsDistinctEntires` - though you may just not have shown those in the question. You may need another space in your concatenation depending on what `CommonFilterCluase` contains. You aren't using the `uldid` or `flightlegid` variables. And so on.